# TYPO3 create folder mount out of fileadmin

Tags: file, typo3, public-html

How can I create a folder and give backend user access rights to it, but not inside **fileadmin** folder, as I don't want this folder to be accessed by browsers. Or is there a way to **create a folder** inside **fileadmin**, **but not being public**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can restrict access from outside with a .htaccess file or configuration.

Also you can define additional file storages other than `/fileadmin` but as far as they are inside webroot they also are visible from outside.

Answer (score 4):

With FAL (TYPO3 > 4.7), you can add a new folder displayed in file list. Just go to your root page (uid 0) and add a `file storage`. There you can set an absolute path to your folder. This folder can be outside of the document root and not accessible via browser.